# Django - TypeError: 'genre' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I’m using Django and I'm having a problem running a Python script that uses Django models

The script that I'm using takes data from an api and loads it into my database, however, I'm getting a TypeError while trying to run it:

```
>>> exec(open('load_from_api.py').read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\commands\shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\commands\shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\qu
ery.py", line 465, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\qu
ery.py", line 387, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
movies.models.DoesNotExist: Movie matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\ma
nager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\qu
ery.py", line 467, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(lookup, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\qu
ery.py", line 499, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\qu
ery.py", line 399, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\ba
se.py", line 443, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % li
st(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'genre' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

**Movie model:**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    tmdb_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    release = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    poster = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    backdrop = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    director = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="directed_movies")
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="acted_movies")
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
```

and a snippet from the script i'm using:

```
for movie in results:
    data = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                       tmdb_id=movie['id'],
                                       release=movie['release_date'],
                                       genre=movie['genre_ids'],
                                       description=movie['overview'],
                                       backdrop=movie['backdrop_path'],
                                       poster=movie['poster_path'])
```

movie['genre_ids'] come in a list form: [42, 67, 80] or [12, 109] for example.

I'm not quiet sure where I'm wrong, any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

When i changed my script to this:

```
for movie in results:
    data = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                       tmdb_id=movie['id'],
                                       release=movie['release_date'],
                                       description=movie['overview'],
                                       backdrop=movie['backdrop_path'],
                                       poster=movie['poster_path'])
    genres = []
    genres = movie['genre_ids']
    for gnre in genres:
        data.genre.add(gnre)
```

It gave me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'genre'
```

Comment: Looks like you need to make `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: no change detected in app!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254033/django-get-or-create-return-error-tuple-object-has-no-attribute/12254139#12254139) to explain the attribute error.

Comment: thank you, that did it for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get_or_create()
>
> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
> created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
> object was created.

so instead of:

```
data = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                   ....)
```

it should be:

```
data, created = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                            ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for movie in results:
    obj, data = Movie.objects.get_or_create(title=movie['title'],
                                       tmdb_id=movie['id'],
                                       release=movie['release_date'],
                                       description=movie['overview'],
                                       backdrop=movie['backdrop_path'],
                                       poster=movie['poster_path'])
    genre_ids = movie['genre_ids']
    genres = Genre.objects.filter(id__in=genre_ids)
    obj.genre.add(*genres)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, it gave me an NameError: name 'Genre' not defined

Comment: You should import Genre model, `from yourapp.models import Genre`

Comment: it gave me AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'genre'

Comment: TypeError: add() argument after ** must be a mapping, not QuerySet

Comment: @mari its only one *